# Overwritting an imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Is it possible to overwrite the definition of a class so that all calls (inside my program or other .py files) receive the overwrite? For example:

```
# package.py
class orgClass:
    def some_method(x):
        return x * x

# my_prog.py
import other_package
from package import orgClass

class orgClass(orgClass):
    def some_method(x):
        return x + x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    other_package.run()

# other_package.py
from package import orgClass

def run():
    o = orgClass()
    x = 5
    print (o.some_method(x)) # would print 10 not 25; however it prints 25
```

I need to alter the implementation of the `orgClass` for this specific program, but I don't want to change source code (of the original package; seems like a bad idea anyhow) so I figured I could just "rewrite" the class implementation in `my_prog.py` and that would take affect to all calls that came from the `__main__.thread`.

Comment: You could import `orgClass` from `my_prog`.

Comment: @internet_user That requires me modifying source code. The class I want to overwrite is from a library (not something I developed). I only need to overwrite a function for this instance, however I want all other .py files that call that class to receive the update defined in `my_prog.py`.

Comment: You can monkey-patch the class in the `package` module, either by modifying the class object directly or by modifying the module object in `sys.modules`. That will only work if you can apply your monkey-patch *before* the code in question does its `import`. Most likely, just modifying the code is going to be the best route: it's simpler, easier to debug, and less likely to introduce subtle bugs elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Note that if it's an open-source library, you can just create your own fork of the library with whatever modifications you need. (If the library isn't open source, you probably need to talk to a lawyer no matter what you do to solve this problem.)

Comment: @DanielPryden While I agree about modifying the original code, the change is only applicable for this program; don't want other programs (who reference the same class for other uses) to get the changes as well (which they would if I modified the source file).

Comment: @pstatix: I'm not sure which of my comments you're responding to. If you're taking the monkey-patching route, that's a runtime modification, so it doesn't affect other programs that use the same library. If you're talking about my comment about forking the library: you just need to ensure the different programs run with different paths (e.g. use a virtualenv to isolate dependencies, which is a best practice anyway).

Comment: @DanielPryden It is an open source library, so modifying it isn't a problem. However, other programs reference `other_package.py`, so making a change would be bad for other programs who use the class as is. What would be the appropriate way to make a change to the class in question that only affects this program, but goes open source library wide? Meaning that other files from the library that use the class receive the changes only for this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here.

Option 1. You can modify the class object directly (monkey-patching):

```
import package

def new_some_method(self, x):
    return x + x

package.orgClass.some_method = new_some_method
```

(Variants on this include monkey-patching the whole `orgClass` object, to similar effect.)

Option 2. You could create a replacement module, and then modify `sys.path` to force it to load first:

```
# replacement-packages/package.py
class orgClass:
    def some_method(self, x):
        return x + x

 # my_prog.py
 sys.path = ['path/to/replacement-packages'] + sys.path

 import package  # loads replacement-packages/package.py
```

(Variants on this include using path files or various shims in `__init__.py`, or modifying `sys.modules` directly.)

Option 3. You could fork the whole `package` project, and modify it to suit your needs. Then you could use a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or some other set-up to only install the modified package as a dependency of your `my_prog` program, while other programs would use the default `python` interpreter which would load the original package.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want to
1) import orgClass
2) adjust orgClass

```
#my_classes.py
import orgClass

class orgClass(orgClass):
    def some_method(x):
        return x+x
```

edit:
To then use this function use

```
from my_classes import orgClass
```

edit:

Now I see your importing is different, then it might be done using argument such as:

```
# package.py
class orgClass:
    def some_method(x):
        return x * x

# my_prog.py
import other_package
from package import orgClass

class orgClass(orgClass):
    def some_method(x):
        return x + x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    other_package.run(orgClass)

# other_package.py

def run(o):
    x = 5
    print (o.some_method(x)) # would print 10 not 25; however it prints 25
```

Comment: In `my_prog.py` I import the class I want to overwrite. But in other `.py` files, they may call `orgClass` but they are calling the original version, not my overwritten version.

Comment: I have done what you are showing here, but the changes do not take affect since other `.py` files do not `import my_prog` to receive the updated class. I need to overwrite the original class in its original file in place.

Comment: You have to call the `my_classes.py`, otherwise it cannot be done. There is no link to your changes between `import orgClass` and using it if you do not provide it (such as my answer, changing imports).

Comment: I do not want to modify the original library to call `from my_prog import orgClass`. I just wanted to temporarily overwrite the function for this program and leave source code files alone. If I cannot do that, then the answer to the question is No.

Comment: The only such edditing would be to redefine the class in the library after it's definition such as `class orgClass(): def some_method()` (... code ...) `class orgClass(orgClass): def some_method(x):` (... code ...)

Comment: But that requires me to edit the original libraries `.py` does it not? I do not want to alter the original file. I was looking for a way to "temporarily redefine" a class so that once I do that, ALL calls from other files get the updated class. However, it appears that if they all call `from package import orgClass` they get the original class, not my update.

Comment: I made second edit, if you are ok with including arguments, but it seems you do not want these.

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge, you have 2 options:

1. Edit the original file `package.py`.
2. Make every file that requires the new method import `my_prog.py`.

Since you don't want the first option, the answer is No - you cannot do that.